# ¿Por que me da este error TaskCanceledException al consumir una api por post?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, api

les comento que estoy realizando una aplicación en asp.net mvc 5 ante la cual estoy consumiendo una api por medio de métodos asíncronos `Task<>`. Para ello tengo un método creado con el cual consumo data mediante request post pero me da una excepción de cancelación de tarea.

Este error solo me pasa al momento de consumir una url en particular ya que cuando consumo los demas por post no tengo este problema. Para consumir las demás urls les paso un token de autorizacion, pero esta url en particular no lo necesita. El error a continuación.

> Se canceló una tarea.
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Se canceló una tarea.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 45:         {
>   Línea 46:             RootObject RootObject = null;
>   Línea 47:             HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
>   Línea 48:             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
>   Línea 49:             {

Metodo para consumir la api:

```
static async Task<Object> PostRutConfirmadoAsync(MiModelo model, string path)
    {
        RootObject RootObject = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            RootObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
        }

        return RootObject;
    }
```

El error me da en esta linea `HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpService.GenerateClient().PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);`

Comment: necesitaría mas detalle del error: puede que le error se dé al consumir el servicio *GenerateClient()*, o al realizar el parser de *response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>*.
Lo mas recomendable es capturar el error en la función *PostRutConfirmadoAsync* y revisar el detalle, porque cada vez que falle esta función va arrojar el error *TaskCanceledException*.

Comment: Trate de capturar el error con un try catch pero cuando lanza esa excepción no entra al bloque del catch...

Comment: Ese error se debe prinipalmente a que excede el tiempo del timeout, intenta asignarle más y con eso debería ser suficiente

Comment: Intentare eso. De igual forma ahora entro al catch y aca esta el mensaje de error aun que creo que no ayuda mucho...

Message: Se canceló una tarea.

Comment: El timeout se lo debo agregar al HttpClient o al Task<>, de ser a este ultimo como se le asigna un timeout? por que estaba probando pasandole como tercer parametro un TimeStamp pero solo me acepta uno de tipo CancellationToken

Comment: Hola, la propiedad `Timeout`de un objeto de tipo `HttpClient` puede establecerse así `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);`

Comment: Esto ya se soluciono, el problema era al pasar los parametros hacia la api como int Gracias a todos por tomarse su tiempo y querer ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes mejorar tu código aplicando un timeout y manejando las posibles excepciones de la siguiente forma

```
static async Task<Object> PostRutConfirmadoAsync(MiModelo model, string path)
{
    try 
    {
        RootObject RootObject = null;
        using (var client = HttpService.GenerateClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, model);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                RootObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce) 
    {
        // Tratar el error de timeout o tarea cancelada
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        // Otros errores (HTTP 500, parsing errors)
    }   

    return RootObject;
}
```

Comment: Sergio tu respuesta fue reportada como baja calidad ya que no soluciona el problema en realidad, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Hola. La excepción que indica OP se produce tanto por un timeout como por otra cualquier excepción producida en el extremo. Hay que controlar dichas excepciones para que el método no falle de forma inesperada. Según la descripción de la excepción: `Se canceló una tarea. Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. ` se observa que existe una excepción no controlada.